# Can Math help to formulate an UPDATE query in SQL through Karnaugh map?

Tags: sql, boolean-logic, karnaugh-map

I've got a database with 2 tables. Let call them **table** and **tableWithUpdatedValues**

The table structure is the same, they have only few columns: **title**, **plot** and **review**. **table** has also a column updated.

The value both can assume are NULL, 1 and 2.

```
Null = '' = string.empty != 1
Null = '' = string.empty != 1
Null = '' = string.empty != 2
1 != 2
```

I want to copy values from **tableWithUpdatedValues** to **table** and set the updated flag to 1 in all cases except one: when the plot value or the review value on the two tables are different AND the destination table value is not null. There is also a difference in the behavior: if the values are different, but the value on **tableWithUpdatedValues** is null I will keep the value on **table**

The concept is pretty easy and intuitive. Null is an unuseful value. 1 and 2 have instead the same value. I will never overwrite 1 or 2 with null, and I will have a conflict on overwriting 1 with 2 or viceversa (so I will not overwrite).

[image]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

I've realized that the table is simmetrical

## Example data

```
Title: Vajont
Plot on table = ''
Plot on tableWithUpdatedValues = 'Nice movie'
Result wanted on table:
plot = 'Nice movie'
updated = 'true'

Title: Lost in Translation
Plot on table = 'Nice movie'
Plot on tableWithUpdatedValues = 'Very nice movie'
Result wanted on table:
plot = 'Nice movie'
updated = 'false'
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (and which version)?

Comment: How do you know which record in tableWithUpdatedValues correspond to a given record in table?  Is there a foreign key and/or id to use?  Maybe posting some sample data would help.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that there is also a column called title which is the PK. I was thinking of using NVL function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
update @myTable
set updated = 0

update t
set plot = ut.plot
    , updated = 1
from @myTable t
inner join @myUpdatedTable ut on ut.title = t.title
where ((t.plot is null or t.plot = '')
        or t.plot = ut.plot)
and ((t.review is null or t.review = '')
        or t.review = ut.review)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/40641)

Note: since you did not specify a RDBMS I did it in SQL Server 2008.  If it does not work, something similar should do it.

Comment: Thanks! There is only one problem.. I have to do the same operation also for the review. If the plot OR the review are in conflict I will treat the row manually in the other case I want the row to be updated.. it's like to define 2 variable: UpdatableForPlot and UpdatableForReview and do the update only if both are true. But I think that your advice is leading me on the right street.. All the field are not null.

Comment: @Revious I've updated my answer per your comment.  Adding a bit more to the where clause should do it.

Comment: thanks. Working on the real data I found another problem. Sometimes the data on ut are null and are valued on t. In that case I will replace ut.plot with NVL(ut.plot, t.plot) but it's a bit annoying because data are NOT NULL but can be '', so NVL will not work (I'm on MySQL 5)

Comment: @Revious You could add a part to the where clause that says "and ut.plot != '' and ut.plot is not null and ut.review != '' and ut.review is not null".  That way those rows won't get considered in the update.

Comment: but I want to consider them. Imagine I have the review which is to update and the plot which is not to update. I want to update the record only on the review, keep the old plot and set updated to 1.